# What does it mean for two theories to be inter-interpretable?

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

Mc Larty, is his article "Exploring Categorical Structuralism", gives a proof that the set theory ZFC is inter-interpretable with ETCS+R, a categorical version of set theory.

Intuitively, I get the idea. But is there any **precise definition of inter-interpretability?**

In terms of proof theory and model theory, what does it mean to say that two theories are inter-interpretable?

In other words, **what are the interesting consequences of inter-interpretability?**

Can you give me a **good reference to read more about those issues?**

Comment: If Mc Larty gives a proof, then presumable they state or cite a precise definition so they can prove it holds.

Comment: It is not a detailed proof. A lot of information is lacking and I wasn't able to get precisely what is the definition.

Comment: See Hodges *Model Theory* or *A Shorter Model Theory*.

Comment: You've misstated the result: ETCS+R and ZFC are interpretable in each other (note that R is already part of ZFC).

Comment: Thanks, @NoahSchweber. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *interpretation* of one theory $T$ in another theory $S$ is essentially an appropriate tuple of formulas $\Phi$ (one formula for each symbol in the language of $S$, plus another formula for "domain") such that in any model $M$ of $T$, we have "$\Phi^T\models S$" - that is, $\Phi$ defines in $M$ a set and some relations/functions on that set which together form a model of $S$.

For example, consider the usual construction of $\mathbb{C}$ as ordered pairs of reals. This corresponds to an interpretation of $Th(\mathbb{C};+,\cdot)$ in $Th(\mathbb{R};+,\cdot)$; the formulas in question are

- $\varphi_{domain}(x,y)\equiv \top$ (the domain is all ordered pairs),
- $\varphi_+(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)\equiv (x_1+y_1=z_1)\wedge (x_2+y_2=z_2)$ (addition is componentwise), and
- $\varphi_\cdot(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)\equiv (x_1\cdot y_1-x_2\cdot y_2=z_1)\wedge(x_1\cdot y_2+x_2\cdot y_1=z_2)$ (multiplication treats the second coordinate like $i$ - note that I'm using subtraction here, which I shouldn't really, but since it's definable in terms of $+$ this is a benign abbreviation).

(A precise definition can be found in either of Hodges' model theory books, and [this blog post of Hamkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/different-set-theories-are-never-bi-interpretable/) - which I also cite below for a technical result - gives a good description of the notion.)

For a more technical example, **forcing** gives a method for constructing interpretations: e.g. the proof that ZFC+$\neg$CH is consistent if ZFC is ultimately amounts to constructing an interpretation $\Phi$ of ZFC+$\neg$CH in ZFC (with a bit of thought taken to handle non-well-founded models).

---

Two theories are then *inter-interpretable* (or *mutually interpretable*) if each is interpretable in the other. Interestingly there is a sharper version, called **bi-interpretability**, which requires that the interpretations commute nicely: given $M\models T$, we need "($M$'s model of $S$)'s model of $T$" to be isomorphic to $M$ (and similarly with $S$ and $T$ switched).

(In fact we require even more than that even: we need such isomorphisms to be *uniformly definable*. But this is a bit technical so I'll ignore it for now.)

This is in general a stronger condition than mere mutual interpretability; see e.g. [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/different-set-theories-are-never-bi-interpretable/) to see a stark difference.